# Flutter: How to add key-value pairs to the JSON structure?

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

in my flutter code, I am creating the following structure

```
{chat_mode: supplier, timestamp: 1605875170638, last_message: Test, members: [K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsACBD, K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsaZJDFDFD]}
```

The structure is created by this code

```
//Create chat_room
  Future<String> createChatRoom(
      {String lastMessage, String chatMode, List<ChatMember> members}) async {
    var newChatRoomRef = _chatRoomReference.push();
    var newChatRoomKey = newChatRoomRef.key;
    await newChatRoomRef.set({
      'last_message': lastMessage,
      'chat_mode': chatMode,
      'members': [members[0].uid, members[1].uid],
      'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    });
    return newChatRoomKey;
  }
```

The `members`, this is how I separate that data at this moment

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.value;
List<dynamic> members = List.of(map["members"]);
```

Now, I need this `members` to be a key-value array. Something like below.

```
members:
  K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsACBD : "link1",
  K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsaZJDFDFD : "link2"
```

My question is, how can create this structure in my above code?

Also after creating it, how can i get the `members` out and read each one of it?

Comment: why don't you use the standard way to create classes and then to en/decode this to/from JSON. If you would have a variable based on nested data classes, this would be a piece of cake